# Can't reference returned BrowserWindow object from method

Tags: c#, coded-ui-tests

I am starting to get into C# from years of other languages, and I feel so basic for even asking this, but I have been scouring this site and the net and just cannot seem to get this to sink in and work. I am trying to create a framework in coded UI so that I can have a library of methods to call to perform actions on browser controls. Here is one of the methods I am trying to use:

```
namespace Functions
{

    public class BrowserFunctions()
    {

       public BrowserWindow browser {get;set;}


        public object launchBrowser()
        {

           browser  = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("https://qawww.test.com/"));

            browser.Maximized = true;

            return browser;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to then be able to reference the browser object I am trying to return from this script:

```
 BrowserWindow mybrowser = new Functions.BrowserFunctions.browser;
```

^^ this line says it is a property but used like a type

```
        //BrowserWindow mybrowser = Functions.BrowserFunctions.browser;

       // mybrowser = new BrowserFunctions();

        UITestControl txtUserEmail = new UITestControl(mybrowser);
        UITestControl txtPassword = new UITestControl(mybrowser);
        UITestControl btnLogin = new UITestControl(mybrowser);
```

I am probably way off base and still trying to learn, but currently failing :) I am grateful to anyone who could help get me going with this.

Comment: Basically since I'm formulating an answer, I'll tell you the way you wrote that line is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
BrowserWindow mybrowser = new Functions.BrowserFunctions.browser;
```

This line literally isn't doing anything. You need to either create a new `BrowserFunctions` object and then assign the browser to it through a set method such as this....

```
BrowserWindow mybrowser = new Functions.BrowserFunctions.browser();
mybrowser = somebrowser;
```

Or you have one already existing and you don't need to `new` it.

```
BrowserWindow mybrowser = Functions.YourBrowserFunction.yourbrowser;
```